# Why is my join() method not working?

Tags: javascript

I want to write a function that takes in a multi-digit number and returns a number that contains the result of each of those numbers squared.

I can successfully turn the number into a string and square each number using the map methods, however when I try to join the array back into a single number, it is failing.

Here's my code:

```
function squareDigits(num){
  let numArray = num.toString().split("").map(Number);
  return numArray.map(function(number){
    return Math.pow(number, 2).join('');
  });
}
squareDigits(52);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this. your .join() mis-placed

```
function squareDigits(num){
  let numArray = num.toString().split("").map(Number);
  return numArray.map(function(number){
    return Math.pow(number, 2)
  }).join('');
}
```

Comment: Brilliant, that makes sense! Thanks.

Comment: Small thing, but it puts the number into a string

Answer (score 0):

`Math.pow` returns a `Number`, not an array, but `Array.prototype.map` does. `join` is a `Array.prototype` method.

Comment: But how come then if I remove the .join() what is returned is an array:
 [25, 4]? I want the result to simply be 254.

Comment: Thanks, I did, and while it works, the number is in a string. I am having trouble converting this back into a number.

Comment: use `parseInt`.